# Translation of Gesamtbetriebsrat

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Would you translate this as 'general works council' or 'workers council', or something else?  The article I'm looking at refers to 'Gesamtbetriebsratsvorsitzende' (presumably the chairman) and later the 'Betriebsrat'...

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Works_council) what "works council" is. -  I guess the term "general" for "Gesamt" is acceptable and also the suggestion by [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Gesamtbetriebsrat.html) supports that.

Comment: Actually, to answer your question: Yes I would do so as dict.cc suggests.

Comment: To clear up any confusion you could add an asterisk which explains what a *Gesamtbetriebsrat* is in contrast to a *Betriebsrat*.

Comment: Both answers seem plausible - thanks.  Going with tohuwawohu's because of the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff), a european inter-institutional terminology database (“Inter-Active Terminology for Europe"), offers

> Gesamtbetriebsrat: **[central works council](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=1392341&langId=&query=gesamtbetriebsrat&sourceLanguage=de&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=en)**
>
> Betriebsrat (besides **[works council](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=972399&langId=&query=betriebsrat&sourceLanguage=de&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=en)**): **[works committee](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=1750266&langId=&query=betriebsrat&sourceLanguage=de&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=en)**, **[employee committees](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do?method=searchDetail&lilId=1487600&langId=&query=betriebsrat&sourceLanguage=de&domain=0&matching=&start=0&next=1&targetLanguages=en)**

But i'm sure that "joint works council" [as proposed by Takkat](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4725/392) is a good match ,too!

Answer (score 3):

This indeed is a very German expression not only that it is composed of long nouns but also as it describes a very special worker's organisation in German companies. Here is my suggestion (from reading translations of various annual financial reports of larger German companies)

> **Betriebsrat:** works council
>   **Gesamtbetriebsrat:** joint works council
>   **Gesamtbetriebsratsvorsitzender:** chairman of the joint works council